# Javascript [object Element]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get some xml datas from webservice. I can access all data but i cannot get one by one.
I want write data to div that has id "code". It writes [object Element]. What i have to do?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var returnValue = localStorage.getItem("returnValue");
            var userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
            alert("Hello" + userName);
            var wsUrl = "http://xxx=GetStocks";

            var soapRequest =
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\ xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"\ xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
  <soap:Body>\
    <GetStocks xmlns="http://sales.xxx.org/">\
      <token>' + returnValue + '</token>\
    </GetStocks>\
  </soap:Body>\
</soap:Envelope>';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wsUrl,
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: soapRequest,
                success: processSuccess,
                error: processError
            });
        });

        function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
            if (status == "success") {
                var stocks = $(req.responseXML).find("pStockInfo");
                var codes = $(req.responseXML).find("Code");
                var stocksCount = stocks.length;

                $("#code").text(codes[0]); //Here i want first code.               
            }
        }

        function processError(data, status, req) {
            alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Xml Data

[image]

I want get first code "FO19428"

Comment: Please insert a `console.log(codes);` before `$("#code").text(codes[0]);` and post the output in your question.

Comment: It would help if you have the XML data inside the question, possibly in a isolated snippet example inside a variable with only the code that focuses on processing it. Aside the fact images are blocked in my browser, I can't copy-paste data from an image into a snippet, fiddle, etc.. to see why/what works for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
 var codes = $(req.responseXML).find("Code");
 var firstCode = codes.eq(0).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

`codes[0]` contains `<code>FO19428</code>`. You can use jQuery's `.text()` function to get it's content:

```
var firstCode = $(codes[0]).text();
```

Here a fiddle:

```js
var responseXML = "<ArrayOfPStockInfo><pStockInfo><Code>FO19428</Code><Name>ITACA KC</Name><Stock>2</Stock></pStockInfo></ArrayOfPStockInfo>";

var codes = $(responseXML).find("Code");
var firstCode = $(codes[0]).text();
$("#code").text(firstCode);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="code"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery `find` return all the elements found.so you must `map` all the elements to their `textContent`.

### Test

```
test('jquery operate on XML', () => {
        const xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`
            <bookstore>
                <book>
                    <title>cooking</title>
                </book>
                <book>
                    <title>drinking</title>
                </book>
            </bookstore>
        `, 'text/xml');
    
        let books = $(xml).find('book title').map(function () {
            return this.textContent;
        }).toArray();
        expect(xml instanceof Document).toBe(true);
        expect(books).toEqual(['cooking', 'drinking']);
    });
```

### Demo

```js
var xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString([
        '<bookstore>',
            '<book>',
                '<title>cooking</title>',
            '</book>',
            '<book>',
                '<title>drinking</title>',
            '</book>',
        '</bookstore>'
    ].join(''), 'text/xml');

var books = $(xml).find('book title').map(function () {
    return this.textContent;
}).toArray();

console.log(books);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```